where do rabbinic Jews get their star from
The rabbinic jews use the star of "David" or Magen "David", I put quotations because nobody knows if David actually had a shield with that star on it. And everything surrounding is weird.
But nonetheless, there are a few verses I've had seen. What is is this verse referring to, because as I can see the star of Remphan is exactly alike to the star of David.
Acts 7:43 KJV

Yea, ye took up the tabernacle of Moloch, And the star of your god Remphan, Figures which ye made to worship them: And I will carry you away beyond Babylon.

I have seen the star of the pagan god Saturn which is 8 points, but I cannot say this is what this verse is referring to at all. Neither anytime I've searched for the star of Remphan, this can also point to rhe seal of Solomon but I highly doubt Jews are using it as the seal of Solomon or else they would call it so, tho I have seen that it has taken origin from it
What is this referring to? and where did the Jews get the star of David from?

